# JavaScript Object.observe on prototype

Tags: javascript

Consider the code below :

```js
function createFoo() {
  var val;

  function Foo() {}
  Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function () {
      return val;
    },
    set: function (value) {
      val = value; 
      document.write('foo value set to : ', value);
    }
  });

  return new Foo();
}



var foo = createFoo();

Object.observe(foo, function (changes) { document.write(changes); });

foo.foo = 'bar';
```

Why is it that `Object.observe`'s handler is never fired? Can an object prototype be "observed"?

(Please, answers *must not* suggest to use some kind of third party library.)

**Update**

Please, read the comments for more information and for the resolution to this problem.

Comment: Note that the `Object.observe` proposal was withdrawn: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe .

Comment: Thank you for that. This was an experiment and I was already concerned about speed. Since O.o doesn't work anyway for the use case that I have, I have moved to extending `EventEmitter` and emitting events instead. I'm choosing the single answer as there is no other answer anyway, so this question can be closed for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
foo.foo = 'bar';
```

does not modify neither foo object nor its prototype thus observe does not report anything.

Here is the version that triggers observer on `this.val = value;` :

```js
function createFoo() {
  

  function Foo() {}
  Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function () {
      return this.val;
    },
    set: function (value) {
      this.val = value; 
      document.write('foo value set to : ', value);
    }
  });

  return new Foo();
}



var foo = createFoo();

Object.observe(foo, function (changes) { document.write("<br>observer:", changes); });

foo.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: So... when using a getter/setter, `Object.observe` won't work, right?

Comment: `Object.observe` triggers on object change. See my update. If your setter modifies the observable object then you will get observe callback notification.

Comment: Hrm. however `this.val` is not the same as the original property name, thus this will set a value to a "random" property name in order to trigger the handler. Sure, it works, however this is just weird. Naturally, replacing `this.val` with `this.foo` will just cause an infinite loop...

Comment: You `define` **virtual** `Property` that is representing some real or computable property. In first case we usually name virtual and internal properties similarly, like: `this._foo = foo;`. Not "random" as you said. Object in JS is a name/value map. Modification of this map is a subject of observation, nothing else.

Comment: "replacing this.val with this.foo will just cause an infinite loop". Sure as you are getting perfect loop of recursion calls.